# I need a function which searches through an array and returns the last set of numbers after the last string?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need a function called `getLastNumbers` which searches through an array and returns the last set of numbers after the last operator.

for example:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, "+", 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, "*", 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, "-", 6, 6, 6, 6] Returns 6666

[1, 1, 1, 1, "+", 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, "*", 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, "-", 6, 6, 6, 6, "+", 3, 3, 3] Returns 333

[7, "*", 7, "-", 6, "+", 3, "+", 6, "+", 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, "+", 6, "-", 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, "*", 9, 9] Returns 99

[5, "*", 5] returns 5
```

To clarify, I will never know how many numbers or operators the user may input.

See my long winded attempt below attempt below:

```
function getLastNumber(arr) {
  let number = arr.filter(i => i === '*' || i === '/' || i === '+' || i === '-').length;

  let counter = 0;
  let arrayLength = arr.length;
  let lastOpIndex = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === '*' || arr[i] === '+' || arr[i] === '-' || arr[i] === '/') {
      counter++;
      if (counter === number) {
        lastOpIndex.push(arr.indexOf(arr[i]));
      }
    }
  }

  let lastOpNum = parseInt(lastOpIndex.toString());
  let startNum = lastOpNum + 1;
  let mathNum = (arrayLength - lastOpNum) - 1;


  let finalArray = [];

  for (let i = startNum; i < arr.length; i++) {
    finalArray.push(arr[i]);
  }

  let strResult = finalArray.toString().split(',').join('');

  let finalResult = parseInt(strResult);

  return finalResult;
}

getLastNumber([1, "+", 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, "+", 6, "+", 9, "*", 6, 6, 6, 3, 6, 6, 6, "-", 5, "*", 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, '/', 6, 8, 9, 9, '*', 8, 8, 8, 7]);
```

Comment: If you may want to accept an answer, delete your question or if it is not answered correctly edit it to clarify what your asking for. it so it won't show up in the unanswered section anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As the question is open again i will extend on my comment. I think they way you're trying to achieve this is a bit to complicated.

Here is my approach just turning the problem arround and starting with the last index instead of the first one.
As soon as I find an operator I just break the loop and return the saved values in reversed order.

```js
function getLastNumber(arr){
 let ret = [];
 for(let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
   if(arr[i] !== '*' && arr[i] !== '+' && arr[i] !== '-' && arr[i] !== '/') {
       ret.push(arr[i]);
   } else {
       break;
   }
 }
 return ret.reverse().toString();
}
console.log(getLastNumber([1, "+", 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, "+", 6, "+", 9, "*", 6, 6, 6, 3, 6, 6, 6, "-", 5, "*", 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, '/', 6, 8, 9, 9, '*', 8, 8, 8, 7]));
console.log(getLastNumber([1, 1, 1, 1, "+", 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, "*", 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, "-", 6, 6, 6, 6, "+", 3, 3, 3]));
console.log(getLastNumber([7, "*", 7, "-", 6, "+", 3, "+", 6, "+", 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, "+", 6, "-", 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, "*", 9, 9]));
console.log(getLastNumber([5, "*", 5]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function filterNumbers(arr){
            let a = arr.lastIndexOf("*"); // find last index of *
            let b = arr.lastIndexOf("+"); // find last index of +
            let c = arr.lastIndexOf("-"); // find last index of -
            let d = arr.lastIndexOf("/"); // find last index of /
            let ind = Math.max(a, b, c, d); //find the max index
            console.log(ind);
            let newarr = arr.splice(ind+1,arr.length); //splice array 
            console.log(newarr);
         return newarr;
        }
     filterNumbers([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, "+", 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, "*", 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6,1]);
          filterNumbers([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, "+", 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, "*", 3, 3, 3, 3,"/", 3, 6, 6, 6, 6,1]);
```